# How to fix nodejs connect to mongo "MongoError: topology was destroyed"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to create nodejs application that query currentOps on mongodb

If the operation running time > I expected , it will kill the operation

Mongodb version : 3.2

Node version : 11.3.0

Mongo connector : MongoClient

```
function connectMongo(server){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    url = "mongodb://" + server + "/"
    MongoClient.connect(url, 
      {auth:
        {
          user:process.env.user,
          password:process.env.password,
        }
      },
     function(err, database) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const db = database.db('admin')
        db.command({currentOp:1},function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          for(var i = 0; i<data.inprog.length;i++) {
              if (data.inprog[i].secs_running > process.env.timechecker && data.inprog[i].op == "query" && ! data.inprog[i].ns.startsWith("local")){ 
            console.log(textMessage(data.inprog[i],server))
            sendSlack(data.inprog[i],server);
            if (data.inprog[i].secs_running > process.env.timeKillOps && IgnoreListChecker(JSON.stringify(data.inprog[i].client)) == false){

console.log("Start Killing process")
console.log(data.inprog[i].opid)
              db.command({killOp:1,op:Number(data.inprog[i].opid)}).catch( err => {
                 console.log(err)
                 })
            }
          }
        }
      })
    database.close()
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  })
}
```

Output :

> Detect long run query
>
> Server : mongoServer
>
> Query  : `{"find":"student","filter":{"student_id":"5388279"}}`
>
> Secs Running : 279
>
> FROM client : "192.168.0.5"
>
> opid : 1365911264
>
> Please check
>
> Start Killing process
>   1365911264
>
> ```
> { MongoError: topology was destroyed
>     at executeCommand (/Users/kant/work/mongo-longrun-query/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/db_ops.js:475:21)
>     at /Users/kant/work/mongo-longrun-query/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:437:24
>     at new Promise (anonymous)
>     at executeOperation (/Users/kant/work/mongo-longrun-query/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:432:10)
>     at Db.command (/Users/kant/work/mongo-longrun-query/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:263:10)
>     at /Users/kant/work/mongo-longrun-query/app/index.js:49:18
>     at result (/Users/kant/work/mongo-longrun-query/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:414:17)
>     at executeCallback (/Users/kant/work/mongo-longrun-query/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:406:9)
>     at handleCallback (/Users/kant/work/mongo-longrun-query/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
>     at db.s.topology.command (/Users/kant/work/mongo-longrun-query/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/db_ops.js:496:5) name: 'MongoError', [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, it resolve after remove database.close()